# Google Cloud instance suspend

Tags: google-compute-engine

Do you try to use free 90 days google cloud platform ?
I try to practice it.
But After I built my instance unbuntu and run it in a few hours. My instance will be suspended by google because violation of Free-trial terms.
So How I can avoid it ?
I want to use my instance for my test lab.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google Cloud Platform Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/terms) in the Suspension section, if Google detects a violation on the Acceptable Use Policy they can suspend the services.

> 4.1 AUP Violations. If Google becomes aware that Customer's or any Customer End User's use of the Services violates the AUP, Google will give Customer notice of the violation by requesting that Customer correct the violation. If Customer fails to correct the violation within 24 hours of Google's request, then Google may Suspend all or part of Customer's use of the Services until the violation is corrected.

In this [link](https://cloud.google.com/terms/aup) you will find the Google Cloud Platform Acceptable Use Policy:

> Customer agrees not to, and not to allow third parties to use the Services:

> - to violate, or encourage the violation of, the legal rights of others (for example, this may include allowing Customer End Users to infringe or misappropriate the intellectual property rights of others in violation of the Digital Millennium Copyright Act);
> - to engage in, promote or encourage illegal activity;
> - for any unlawful, invasive, infringing, defamatory or fraudulent purpose (for example, this may include phishing, creating a pyramid scheme or mirroring a website);
> - to intentionally distribute viruses, worms, Trojan horses, corrupted files, hoaxes, or other items of a destructive or deceptive nature;
> - to interfere with the use of the Services, or the equipment used to provide the Services, by customers, authorized resellers, or other authorized users;
> - to disable, interfere with or circumvent any aspect of the Services;
> - to generate, distribute, publish or facilitate unsolicited mass email, promotions, advertisings or other solicitations (“spam”); or
> - to use the Services, or any interfaces provided with the Services, to access any other Google product or service in a manner that violates the terms of service of such other Google product or service.

If you don’t know what you are doing wrong, I recommend you contact support.
As you already have a Free trial account you can have chat support through  [Console Support Center](https://console.cloud.google.com/support/chat?_ga=2.201203500.305402083.1598273128-638966553.1591892739), also, you can visit the following [link](https://cloud.google.com/support) for more information.